# How do I list all child categories that apply to current post?

Tags: categories

On my site, I am working on categorizing pictures based on what is in them and am having trouble listing the categories that apply to the post. For instance: A post might include a picture of an ice cream cone with three flavors of ice cream.

My category hierarchy for this post might be:

Flavors ->Vanilla, Mint Chip, Chocolate

Style ->Cone

However, I cannot seem to get a list that includes just children of 'flavors' or 'style', without listing all checked categories.

Essentially I am hoping to have two, nicely organized lists, where one lists the flavors and the other lists the style.  Just I don't want them both in the same list.

Is this possible?

-get_categories seems to have the proper arguments, but I have not been able to work it out.
-the_category seems like it is close, but it doesn't allow for excluding a particular category from a list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having two separate [taxonomies](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies) may make sense for you in this case.

Comment: Oh, wow, I didn't even know that ability existed.  I ended up installing a plugin that creates and manages taxonomies.  Thank you so much!